# php special chars not decoding

Tags: php, special-characters, html-entities

Im passing some strings between teo php pages through a form input. The strings have HTML special characters (á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ) and i need them to display correctly.

THis is my form:

```
<form action="test.php"> <input type="text" name="message" style="" value="" /> </form>
```

and this is test.php:

```
$message=htmlentities($_POST['message']);
```

my goal is to achieve that $message contains the special characters exactly as how they where typed:
for example if the string from the form was: 'áñ' I want $message ='áñ' and not their html equivalent, "`&aacute;&ntilde;`"

EDIT:

for being completly clear, if I do this:

echo $message=htmlentities($_POST['message']);

the borowser displays correctly áñ, however the php variable contains "`&aacute;&ntilde;`". I want the php variable to be áñ, not "`&aacute;&ntilde;`";

iv tried applying htmlspecialchars_decode; utf8_decode and some other php functions, with absolutely no luck.
Can some1 help me?
Thanks

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the correct charset in your HTML page that contains your form.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```

If you are using a PHP page, put the following at the top of your file:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: did you use htmlpecialchars instead of htmlentities?